# Unable to install scipy in Cgywin

Tags: python, numpy, pip, scipy, cygwin

I am new to cygwin and python and trying to install scipy on Cygwin with the following command:

**pip install SciPy-1.8.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl**

But it says ERROR: SciPy-1.8.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I saw various posts and they say that we need numpy+mkl for installing scipy so I tried to install
numpy-1.22.4+vanilla-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl but it also says that this particular wheel is not supported.

My Python is 64 bits and the version is 3.8.12.

I am very confused and have the following questions:

1. I tried to find the version of the tags that my pip supports using **import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())** but it gave me AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'pep425tags'. I tried to update pip but in vain. How to find out the supported versions?
2. What is the exact procedure to install scipy?
3. Many answers on the internet use files like scipy-0.15.1-cp33-**none**-win_amd64.whl but I am not able to find any file with "none" in it. The files that I find are like 'SciPy‑1.8.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl' in format. Can you please help me to find it out?
4. I have installed cpython using pip install cPython command. Do I really need it?

Please help me if you can.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just rename the package to the following:

```
SciPy-1.8.1-cp38-none-any.whl
```

then install with:

```bash
python -m pip install SciPy-1.8.1-cp38-none-any.whl
```